# Fill masked array values with reflect padding

Tags: python, c++, numpy

I have a square matrix (image) with masked values in an area. The mask corresponds to missing values in areas close to the border (always). I want to create a new image where the masked values are replaced with the reflect padding of the values where actual image values exist. How can I do so in python or C++?

In the example below I want to replace (left panel) the yellow area with the reflected image of the middle panel, where data exist. The result should be something like the right panel image (the  padding here  is not the appropriate reflect padding I am after, as I just used the naive recipe  `right_image = np.where(temp.mask,middle_image[::-1,::-1],middle_image)`)

[image]

**edit**: I tried to transverse the image row by row, and use numpy reflect padding, with the code below, but it doesn't work in all regions (bottom left is problematic):

```
# Row Reflect 
# Here out_image is the original image, where -2 is no data value
xx = []
for i in range(6000): # Number of rows
    temp1 = np.ma.array(out_image[0,i,:],mask= out_image[0,i,:]==-2) # Create mask per row, -2 is the masked value
    edges = ma.flatnotmasked_edges(temp1) # Find edges
    #if edges is not None:
    xx += [np.expand_dims(np.pad(temp1.data[edges[0]:edges[1]],((edges[0],temp1.shape[0]-edges[1])),mode='reflect'),0)]
out = np.concatenate(xx)
#out = out.reshape(2000,2000)
```

The result is incorrect. 
[image]

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to create a new image of the same size with binary data/nodata cell values, is that correct? Or do you already have the binary image and are attempting to use it to mosaic two images together? You mention C++ but have no C++ code, have you used GDAL in C++ previously, if not it might be a very steep learning curve.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I have the binary/masked image, and I am trying to fill the masked values (where no data exist) with the reflection of the part of the image where data exist. It is not exactly mosaic two images, it is data augmentation for deep learning training. I've used GDAL minimally (am mostly working with python + rasterio for this), but I am comfortable with C++, if it can solve the problem.

Comment: Oh I see.. the problem is you're getting reflection which works well on the left but not so much on the bottom. Unless you're doing this *a lot* I would tackle it in PhotoShop or GIMP.. one tip: use GeoTIFF examiner (or write a quick python script) to 'save' the georeference as editing in either package *destroys the georeference* then use the examiner again to restore the georeference (or not, a worlded TIFF is usable in most packages).